# How to hide certain children(). of a parent(). div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display only `div.card1` when a user clicks on a selection menu I have made

```
<table id="flowerTheme">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="card1">
         <div class="guess"><a href="#" id="flower1" class="quickFlipCta"><img src="Test Pictures/QuestionMark.gif" /></a></div>
         <div class="remember"><a href="#" class="quickFlipCta"><img src="Test Pictures/flower.gif" /></a></div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="card2">
         <div class="guess"><a href="#" id="flower1" class="quickFlipCta"><img src="Test Pictures/QuestionMark.gif" /></a></div>
         <div class="remember"><a href="#" class="quickFlipCta"><img src="Test Pictures/flower.gif" /></a></div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have a function that toggles the class 'selected' when the user clicks on an image. The following works perfectly:

```
if($('.flowerThemePic').hasClass('selected') && $('.sixCardLayout').hasClass('selected')) {
    $('#flowerTheme').css('display', 'inline');
```

However, as I stated before, I would like to have `card2` to not be displayed. I have tried:

```
if($('.flowerThemePic').hasClass('selected') && $('.sixCardLayout').hasClass('selected')) {
        $('#flowerTheme').not('.card2').css('display', 'inline')
```

But this does not do anything. I have also tried:

```
if($('.flowerThemePic').hasClass('selected') && $('.sixCardLayout').hasClass('selected')) {
        $('#flowerTheme').find('div').not('.card2').css('display', 'inline')
```

But this hides both cards. What would be the right method of displaying `card1` and not `card2`?

Comment: $('.flowerThemePic') is in your code, but is now shown in your HTML. This makes your question difficult to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#flowerTheme').css('display', 'inline');
$('.card2').hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

What about :

```
$('#flowerTheme .card2').hide();
```

?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it looks to me that `card1` and `card2` should be `id`, not `class`. The difference is that IDs are supposed to be unique, while classes are supposed to be re-used. Since you're using `card1` and `card2` to uniquely identify those cards, they should be IDs. Furthermore, they *probably* need a class as well: probably `class="card"`, so they can be referred to as a group.

Secondly, I think you should be using CSS, not jQuery for the actual hiding/showing. Consider this:

```
table#flowerTheme.selection-made :not(.selected) .card
{
    display: none;
}
```

This would hide any element that has `class="card"` that doesn't have any parent with `class="selected"`. Note the `.selection-made` on `#flowerTheme` -- this allows the default case to show every card, but then when someone clicks, you do `$('#flowerTheme').addClass('selection-made');` and then `$(this).addClass('selected');` (assuming you're using `$(wherever selected goes).click()` for this). It's a bit unclear from your question exactly where the `selected` class is being added, but I'd recommend doing it this way. It is far more easily maintained, jQuery has to do less work, and it leaves you with a very simple and easy way to expand the list of cards.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a javascript function to hide children...

```
function hideSpecificChildren(childClass){
     var child = document.getElementByClass(childClass);
     if(tab.style.display == "block") {
        tab.style.display = "none";
     }else {
    tab.style.display = "block";
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#flowerTheme .card2').css('display','none').parent().show();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XBgUx/3/)**

**OR**

```
$('#flowerTheme .card2').hide().parent().show();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XBgUx/4/)**